# conda install and conda build result in different dependency versions

Tags: python, conda, hdf5, h5py, conda-build

I'm trying to build a package which includes `h5py`. When using `conda build`, it seems to install the wrong version of the dependency. It installs `3.2.1-py37h6c542dc_0`, which includes `hdf5: 1.10.6-nompi_h6a2412b_1114`.

The problem is that this `hdf5` lib, seems to have these setting:

`(Read-Only) S3 VFD: yes`

This causes an error for me. When just running `conda install h5py==3.2.1`, it does install the right version (`hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h3c11f04_101`).

Why is there a difference?

Comment: I'm skeptical of the conclusion that having a feature *enabled* (S3 VFD) in the build is problematic. Users usually complain when Conda builds are *not* compiled with the optional features they require. However, this probably is a separate question.

Comment: I don't know, but when trying to use my build it seems that there is a mismatch between h5py and hdf5, as some symbols can't be found. Something ROS3 related. Downgrading to h5py==3.1.0 does the trick, but obviously I'd rather prefer to use a more up to date version.

Comment: Missing symbols are usually from mixing channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Why is there a difference?*

Using `conda install h5py=3.2.1` additionally includes all the previous constraints in the current environment, whereas during a `conda build` run, a new environment is created only with requirements that the package specifies. That is, it is more like running `conda create -n foo h5py=3.2.1`.

So, that covers the mechanism, but we can also look at the particular package dependencies to see why the current environment constrains to the older `hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h3c11f04_101`, which OP states is preferred. Here is the package info for the two:

**hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h6a2412b_1114**

```bash
$ mamba search --info conda-forge/linux-64::hdf5[version='1.10.6',build='nompi_h6a2412b_1114']

hdf5 1.10.6 nompi_h6a2412b_1114
-------------------------------
file name   : hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h6a2412b_1114.tar.bz2
name        : hdf5
version     : 1.10.6
build       : nompi_h6a2412b_1114
build number: 1114
size        : 3.1 MB
license     : LicenseRef-HDF5
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h6a2412b_1114.tar.bz2
md5         : 0a2984b78f51148d7ff6219abe73509e
timestamp   : 2021-01-08 23:10:11 UTC
dependencies: 
  - libcurl >=7.71.1,<8.0a0
  - libgcc-ng >=9.3.0
  - libgfortran-ng
  - libgfortran5 >=9.3.0
  - libstdcxx-ng >=9.3.0
  - openssl >=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a
  - zlib >=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0
```

**hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h3c11f04_101**

```bash
$ mamba search --info conda-forge/linux-64::hdf5[version='1.10.6',build='nompi_h3c11f04_101']

hdf5 1.10.6 nompi_h3c11f04_101
------------------------------
file name   : hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h3c11f04_101.tar.bz2
name        : hdf5
version     : 1.10.6
build       : nompi_h3c11f04_101
build number: 101
size        : 3.0 MB
license     : HDF5
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/hdf5-1.10.6-nompi_h3c11f04_101.tar.bz2
md5         : 9f1ccc4d36edf8ea15ce19f52cf6d601
timestamp   : 2020-07-31 12:26:29 UTC
dependencies: 
  - libgcc-ng >=7.5.0
  - libgfortran-ng >=7,<8.0a0
  - libstdcxx-ng >=7.5.0
  - zlib >=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0
```

The difference here is that the latter works with older versions of `libgcc-ng`, `libstdcxx-ng`, and `libgfortran-ng` (below 9.3.0), as well as has no constraint on `openssl` or `libcurl`. So, we can guess that the current environment where the `conda install h5py=3.2.1` was invoked has one of these restrictions.